# Having issues with a VBScript

Tags: vbscript, process, wmi

This code works on some computers and on others it doesn't.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set service = GetObject("winmgmts:")
i=0
Do Until i=3
    bIsRunning = False
    i=i
    For Each Process In service.InstancesOf.("Win32_Process")
        If Process.Name = "chrome.exe" Then
            bIsRunning = True
        End If
    Next
    If Not bIsRunning Then
        WshShell.Run Chr(34) & "C:\dir\dir\chrome.exe" & Chr(34), 1
    End If
    WScript.Sleep 10000
Loop
```

`Chrome.exe` is just a example. I don't know what causes the issue but each computer has the specified file in the correct place and it just fails to run it on some. I forgot to mention when the file doesn't start there is no error.

Comment: Your description of desired and actual behavior of your code is rather vague. Did you verify that the process isn't already running? How?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i figured it out. I rewrote the process in c# and used a timer with the command

```
Proccess.createnowindow=true;
```